# MySQL Update Trigger is updating every single record on the table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, sql-update

I'm working on a trigger for an audit table in MySQL. There's 2 tables and 2 separate triggers:
clients and aud_clients

One trigger is an AFTER INSERT ON clients and the other one is AFTER UPDATE ON clients.
Basically every time a record is inserted into clients, a record should also be inserted into aud_clients, and if its an UPDATE on clients, the update on aud_clients should put the old data into old_[Whatever] fields and new one into new_[Whatever] fields.

The operations themselves are working, the problem is that, upon having an UPDATE on clients, every single record on aud_clients becomes the newly updated record.

Output example of what's going on

```
code old_name   old_date              old_credit   new_name    new_date       new_credit
10  jello   2019-11-28 19:38:09 2342    100234.20   jam   2019-11-28 19:41:23   11145580    
10  jello   2019-11-28 19:38:09 2342    100234.20   jam   2019-11-28 19:41:23   11145580
10  jello   2019-11-28 19:38:09 2342    100234.20   jam   2019-11-28 19:41:23   11145580
```

This is the update trigger

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER aud_upd AFTER UPDATE ON clientes
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
        UPDATE aud_clientes SET
            aud_clientes.cod_cliente = NEW.Cod_cliente,
            aud_clientes.nombre_antes = OLD.nombre_cliente,
            aud_clientes.nombre_despues = NEW.nombre_cliente,
            aud_clientes.telefono_antes = OLD.telefono,
            aud_clientes.telefono_despues = NEW.telefono,
            aud_clientes.credito_antes = OLD.credito_max,
            aud_clientes.credito_despues = NEW.credito_max,
            aud_clientes.fecha_creacion_antes = OLD.fecha_creacion,
            aud_clientes.fecha_creacion_despues = NEW.fecha_creacion,
            aud_clientes.tipo_transaccion = 'UPD',
            aud_clientes.modificado_por = current_user(),
            aud_clientes.fecha = current_timestamp();
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

The INSERT trigger is working as intended, but in case you want to see it:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER aud_ins AFTER INSERT ON clientes
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO aud_clientes (
            aud_clientes.cod_cliente,
            aud_clientes.nombre_antes,
            aud_clientes.nombre_despues,
            aud_clientes.telefono_antes,
            aud_clientes.telefono_despues,
            aud_clientes.credito_antes,
            aud_clientes.credito_despues,
            aud_clientes.fecha_creacion_antes,
            aud_clientes.fecha_creacion_despues,
            aud_clientes.tipo_transaccion,
            aud_clientes.modificado_por,
            aud_clientes.fecha
        ) VALUES (
            NEW.cod_cliente,
            null,
            NEW.nombre_cliente,
            null,
            NEW.telefono,
            null,
            NEW.credito_max,
            null,
            NEW.fecha_creacion,
            'INS',
            current_user(),
            current_timestamp()
        );
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Lastly, if you want to look at the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE clientes (
    cod_cliente INT NOT NULL,
    nombre_cliente VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    fecha_creacion datetime not null,
    telefono VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    credito_max DOUBLE(10, 2),
    PRIMARY KEY (cod_cliente)
    );
    commit;

CREATE TABLE aud_clientes (
    cod_cliente INT,
    nombre_antes VARCHAR(100),
    fecha_creacion_antes datetime,
    telefono_antes VARCHAR(100),
    credito_antes DOUBLE(10,2),
    nombre_despues VARCHAR(100),
    fecha_creacion_despues datetime,
    telefono_despues VARCHAR(100),
    credito_despues DOUBLE(10,2),
    modificado_por varchar(100),
    fecha datetime,
    tipo_transaccion varchar(100)
    );
    commit;
```

Notice that there's no need to establish relationships or keys on the aud_clientes table. I used to have the cod_cliente as its primary on not null auto_increment, but no record was being updated (and that was probably because it was running into an error when it tried to give the same code to multiple records) so I deleted it.

Comment: Well, you have no `WHERE` clause on the `UPDATE` statement, so it affects all rows there are. But isn't updating the audit table wrong or at least not optimal anyway? You would overwrite the information about a previously done change whenever there is a change. So you cannot track back beyond one change.

Comment: it's an uni project, it doesn't go that far.

Comment: And thank you, that solved it.